# Exception: NoSuchMethodError occurs when i am casting response

Tags: flutter, casting

I'm new in flutter and i'm trying to get list in list view. I searched a lot on this but i did not find something. Exception occurs when i'm trying to cast response of API and list view shows nothing.

Exception: 
           `Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' has no instance method 'map' with matching arguments.
I/flutter (21020): Receiver: _LinkedHashMap len:2
I/flutter (21020): Tried calling: map<Post>(Closure: (dynamic) => Post)
I/flutter (21020): Found: map<K2, V2>((K, V) => MapEntry<K2, V2>) => Map<K2, V2>`

```
  final response = await client.get('http:url');

  return compute(parsePosts, response.body);
}

List<Post> parsePosts(String responseBody) {
  final parsed = json.decode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

  return parsed.map<Post>((json) => Post.fromJson(json)).toList();
}
```

My JSON is like that

```
     {
    "status": "1",
    "category": [
        "Artificial Intelligence",
        "big data",
        "Cyber Security",
        "Data Science",
        "Software Development"
    ]
}
```

I want to show a list data in list view in Flutter. If you have any query or something regarding code then can ask me. Hope I will get best solution from this community.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to cast it? You could use an actual Model and define a `toMap()` method

Comment: Actually i also don't know what is need for cast here, as i told i'm new on flutter, This is my 2nd day on flutter. I searched for listview and this is working for another URL where i found   https://grokonez.com/flutter/flutter-http-client-example-listview-fetch-data-parse-json-background  but this is not working for my API why...??

Comment: API is hitting but data is not showing, can you suggest me another link or something where can i find better solution. because i found many videos or links but they are also working same as it.